# Relation between functions

Tags: functions

Consider the following relation with two function $q$ and $p$:
$$ q(x)=\sum_{k\ge 1}p(x/k)$$
Is it possible to obtain the formula for $p(x)$?

Comment: Do you mean $\sum_{k=1}^\infty$?And are you given $q(x)$?

Comment: Yes, $ q(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}p(x/k)$.